# Twitter API not returning all tweets

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have create app to get all tweets for particular tag `#comstor`:

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23comstor
```

The search result is getting many more tweets but when I call the search API it is getting only 15 tweets, I have passed `count=100`.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23comstor&count=100&include_rts=1
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search): "[...] the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead."